# How can we disable an unused smoke detector?

Tags: smoke-detectors

We have wired ADT smoke detectors now. Our old free standing detector is chirping. How can we disable it without taking it off the wall?

Comment: If disused, why not remove it? You will at least need to remove it from the mount to take the battery out. If it's too old to be reliable, it should be properly recycled (many detectors have a small amount of radioactive material in them, and should not be discarded in trash.) If it still works, you should put a fresh battery in, rather than disabling it, if you are not going to remove it. Extra smoke detectors are not a bad thing...

Answer (score 2):

Put a battery in it. Why wouldn't you want an additional layer of fire protection?

Comment: It’s on the ceiling above a stairway. Apparently my husband put it there when he wasn’t 93. If we remove it we won’t have to deal with it again. There is a third smokevand CO detector in the same area.

Comment: I agree with this answer if it was installed less than 10 years ago (the usable life of most smoke detectors). Otherwise, the correct action is to remove and replace it--since there are already new smoke detector replacements installed nearby in this case, the correct action would be to remove it if it is over 10 years old.